# Create alias for path to app. GIT bash

Tags: git, zend-framework

How to create alias for path to app like:

```
zf = 'd:/wamp64/bin/zf/bin/zf.bat'
```

and use with git bash:

```
zf create project app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A git bash should have a `~/.bashrc`, if you launch it with `bash -i -l` (bash is in `<path/to/git>\usr\bin\bash.exe`)

`~` should be in `%USERPROFILE%`

Edit `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc` and add an `alias zf = /d/wamp64/bin/zf/bin/zf.bat'`

Comment: $ source ~/.basrc
bash: /c/Users/R1sen/.basrc: No such file or directory

Comment: @ПётрЛитвинович Exactly: you need to create it.

Comment: 1. Create file  ".bashrc" in c:/Users/ %USERPROFILE% and add in file: alias zf='/d/wamp64/bin/zf/bin/zf.bat'. It works!